# Rails query associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm forking a repo off another to be a standalone for a client and for whatever reason I'm having a brain freeze.

Looking to set specific queries to only hit this one Region: Southwest and then all locations associated.

So naturally the model structure is:

```
Region
has_many :locations

Location
belongs_to :region
```

I'm looking at updating some code to specifically hit the Region Southwest in some helpers and it's far too clunky.

```
def southwest_general
 Region.where(name: 'Southwest')
end

def southwest_locations
 Location.where(region_id: 5)
end

def all_locations
 southwest_locations.all.map do |loc|
  pin = { icon: pin_path(loc.region_id) }
  loc.attributes.merge(pin)
 end
end
```

I'm really looking at updating the southwest_locations method to hit the Region model through Locations. I thought I could do something:

```
def southwest_locations
 Location.includes(:regions).where('regions.name =?', 'Southwest').references(:regions)
end
```

But that's really more of a search not a db query right?

Comment: but you don't update anything. try southwest_general.locations.update_all(column: value) is that you what?

Comment: Really just looking to set the method to return the specific region. In the case of southwest_general it's being set solely to return the region of Southwest. In southwest_locations I just want to return all locations associated with the region Southwest but querying through the Location model but NOT using the region_id.

Comment: Location.joins(:region).where(regions: {id: 5})

Comment: As soon as I typed that I did a query with Location.joins(:region).where('regions.name = ?', 'Southwest').all and that worked. But  @NeverBe works as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locations for particular region

```
Location.joins(:region).where(regions: {id: 5})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this like this, which I think shows the intent far better:

```
Region.find_by(name: 'Southwest').locations
```

I should note that this will perform two queries.